# MySQL/Amazon RDS error: "you do not have SUPER privileges..."

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, sql-grant

I'm attempting to copy my mysql database from an Amazon EC2 to an RDS:

I successfully did a `mysqldump` of my database into my root folder using this:

```
root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~# mysqldump my_database -u my_username -p > my_database.sql
```

Then I tried to transfer this .sql file to my new RDS database:

```
root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:~# mysql my_database -u my_username -p -h  
my_new_database.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com < my_database.sql
```

Unfortunately, I get following error message:

```
You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled 
(you *might* want to use  the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

I tried to `GRANT SUPER..` in a variety of ways but I'm getting errors when I try to do that too. Typing `mysql > FLUSH privileges;` doesn't work either.

I'm a mysql beginner so sorry for such an easy question. Thoughts?

Comment: You can't `GRANT SUPER` on RDS. RDS offers no way to get SUPER privileges.

Comment: Use same MySQL username for creating dump and restoring it (For connection and DEFINER keyword in the dump). Changing log_bin_trust_function_creators is not the desired solution. The worst thing is to use -f parameter in this case

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Per http://getasysadmin.com/2011/06/amazon-rds-super-privileges/, you need to set `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to 1 in [AWS console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/), to load your dump file without errors.

If you want to ignore these errors, and load the rest of the dump file, you can use the `-f` option:

```
mysql -f my_database -u my_username -p -h  
my_new_database.xxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com < my_database.sql
```

The `-f` will report errors, but will continue processing the remainder of the dump file.

Comment: hi @Ross, thanks for this. Unfortunately, using `-f` didn't help. I got the same error. Using your link, i'm having trouble with the RDS Cli tools syntax. Meaning, when I go to change the privileges I get the following error: `rds-modify-db-parameter-group:  Malformed input-Unrecognized option: 
 -–parameters=name=log_bin_trust_function_creators,
Usage:
rds-modify-db-parameter-group
        DBParameterGroupName  --parameters  "name=value, value=value,
       method=value" [ --parameters "name=value, value=value, method=value" ...]
        [General Options]
`

Comment: here's my command that gives me the above error: `./rds-modify-db-parameter-group mygroup -–parameters "name=log_bin_trust_function_creators, value=on, method=immediate" –I="accesskeyxxxxxx" –S="secretkeyxxxxxxxx"` I know it has to be a quotation or double-dash issue i but none of those types of changes is working so far, ugh!

Comment: The `-f` option will not make the errors go away, it will just allow the non-offending SQL statements in the file to be processed. From what I've read, RDS is choking on stored procedures in the dump file. Try creating a dump file without store procedures and see if that loads OK: `mysqldump --routines=0 --triggers=0 --events=0 my_database -u my_username -p`

Comment: At least I can load all the data with the `-f` option. Second phase might be to dump only routines/stred proc, etc separately

Comment: I have updated the parameter group of the Master node with log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1; I have run a ```sed -ie "s/DEFINER=\`a-z0-9A-Z*\`@\`a-z0-9A-Z*\`/DEFINER=CURRENT_USER /g" localsqlfile```; But I am still getting the same error of ```Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation``` and ```Access denied for user 'username'@'%' to database 'mysql'``` when running with the -f command.

Answer (score 212):

1. Open the RDS web console.
2. Open the “Parameter Groups” tab.
3. Create a new Parameter Group. On the dialog, select the MySQL family compatible to your MySQL database version, give it a name and confirm.
   Select the just created Parameter Group and issue “Edit Parameters”.
4. Look for the parameter `log_bin_trust_function_creators` and set its value to `1`.
5. Save the changes.
6. Open the “Instances” tab. Expand your MySQL instance and issue the “Instance Action” named “Modify”.
7. Select the just created Parameter Group and enable “Apply Immediately”.
8. Click on “Continue” and confirm the changes.
9. Wait for the "Modifying" operation to be completed.
10. Again, open the “Instances” tab. Expand your MySQL instance and expand “Instance Action” tab and select "Reboot".

**A reboot isn't necessary** since `log_bin_trust_function_creators` has `apply type = dynamic`. At least this is true if your RDS already has an attached parameter group and you edit it, as opposed to creating a new parameter group. Merely save the parameter edit and you're good to go.

Comment: When I created a new parameter group and tested, it didn't work. I worked after rebooting.

Comment: It also worked for me after rebooting.

Answer (score 36):

For me, there was only 2 commands in my dump file which required SUPER privileges:

- `SET @@GLOBAL.gtid_purged`
- `SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN`

According to the [mysqldump docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-gtid-purged) you can disable these with `--set-gtid-purged=OFF`.

Then looking at [man mysqldump](https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mysqldump/):

> Use ON if the intention is to deploy a new replication slave using only some of the data from the dumped server. Use OFF if the intention is to repair a table by copying it within a topology. Use OFF if the intention is to copy a table between replication topologies that are disjoint and will remain so.

So I decided to add `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` to my `mysqldump` command and then I could successfully import the resulting dump file.

Answer (score 34):

The problem with triggers and stored procedures in the dump file is that these definitions include the user who the stored procedure should be created by, the DEFINER. The user most likely doesn't exist in the RDS so a error is then raised. To be able to load the dump file you can remove the DEFINER using sed or Perl and create the stored procedure/trigger with the user who is performing the import.

```
perl -pe 's/\sDEFINER=`[^`]+`@`[^`]+`//' < mysqldump.sql > mysqldump.fixed.sql
```

Now you should be able to load the fixed dump file

```
mysql my_database -u my_username -p -h rds_host < mysqldump.fixed.sql
```

As said in earlier answer, you should set the DB Parameter:

```
log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1
```

Comment: Cleaning up definers can also be accomplished with sed: sed -i 's/DEFINER=`OldDefiner`@`localhost`/DEFINER=`NewDefiner`@`localhost`/g' ./TargetSqlFile.sql

Answer (score 6):

As defined in AWS documentation triggers, procedures, and functions are disabled by default because binary logging is enabled by default. Disabling basically makes your db more secure, but if you have properly secured through the network it won't matter.

Follow these steps and your problem will be fixed
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/

Also you shouldn't use definers when creating procedures. A simple sed command can remove it.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to editing

> log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1

you need to remove all ***DEFINER*** from your dump file, check the following link for ***SED*** command that can help cleaning your sql dump file.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/07/02/using-mysql-triggers-and-views-in-amazon-rds/#comment-10968243

Answer (score 4):

To complete @arun-r's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30874794/65603), a reboot is necessary when you create a new parameter group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After used arun-r answer, if the problem is not solved you need to modify your dump file. It is simple.

In the dump file you will find lines like :

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`username_from_dumped_database`@`host_from_dumped_database` PROCEDURE `procedure_or_function_name`()
BEGIN
```

You have to replace :

- `username_from_dumped_database` by your username on rds database.
- `host_from_dumped_databse` by `%`

I don't know why but this trick worked for me.
A simple text editor is enough to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to set up a parameter in **AWS/RDS** is by creating a parameter group just like the other responses mentioned here.

For this particular case, set the variable `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to **1** in the **parameters section** when creating a new **parameter group**.

Modify your database, and then select your new **parameter group** at **DB parameter group** under the **Additional configuration** section.

Despite I enabled *Apply Immediately*, it didn't work for me (MySQL v8). It worked after **rebooting**!

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked with over 200 votes is the answer in an ideal situation where the sql file has acceptable commands the RDS Service honors. It’s very important to note that the Parameter Group associated with your RDS instance allows you to set global variables and you should not try to set global variables any other way. **As a Managed Service, RDS restricts what global variables you can set to preserve the stability** of the Managed Service in a cloud environment. Second, a lot of answers here say “follow my steps if you are creating a new parameter group”. In fact, it is irrelevant if you are creating a new Parameter Group or have an existing Paramter Group. What is relevant is if the global variable is **modifiable**, which as the name implies RDS allows you to change it, and whether it is static or dynamic. If it is **static and modifiable**, you need to do a **reboot**; if it is **dynamic and modifiable**, you do **not** need to do a **reboot**.

**With that said, so what if you try the 200+ votes solution and it doesn’t work? Follow these next steps to troubleshoot**:

1. Verify the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` is enabled:

   ```
   SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin_trust_function_creators';
   +---------------------------------+-------+
   | Variable_name                   | Value |
   +---------------------------------+-------+
   | log_bin_trust_function_creators | ON    |
   +---------------------------------+-------+
   ```

   If it is enabled when logging into the mysql shell and running the above command, proceed to step 2.
2. Open up the SQL file. Check the top and bottom of the sql file. If there is a command that is setting global variables, comment this out. **Global Variables can only be set in the Parameter Group in the context of AWS RDS**. For example, you might see **GTID_PURGED** set. Comment it out:

   ```
    -- SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ ‘’;
   ```

   RDS does not give you full admin access. Set Global Variables in Parameter Groups, if the variable shows as modifiable.

   There could possibly be more lines that need to be commented out, as per the AWS internal documentation:

   ```
    SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN= 0;
    SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED=/*!80000 '+'*/ '';
    SET @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN = @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN;
    SET @@SESSION.SQL_LOG_BIN = @MYSQLDUMP_TEMP_LOG_BIN;
   ```
3. Step 1 and 2 should suffice for most troubleshooting cases. Another option you may consider is when the SQL file itself has unexpected behavior, such as a Foreign Key Constraint on a table that has not yet been defined. MySQL provides the -f flag to force changes even when there are errors:

   ```
    mysql -u userName -p -f -D dbName < script.sql
   ```

   I personally do not like resorting to the force command because if there is existing data in the database that is supposed to depend on foreign key constraints, you will later face issues on data integrity. Second, if the force flag ignores the creation of a table for some reason, and your application relies on that table, you will be greeted with errors when trying to load that application. As an alternative to using the -f flag, set the **set-gtid-purged** flag to **OFF** when doing a mysqldump:

   ```
    mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF dbName > dump.sql
   ```

   This prevents globals from being set when doing a dump, such as the SET @@GLOBAL.GTID_PURGED which had to be commented out. IMPORTANT: --set-gtid-purged=OFF is not supported if you are using MariaDB, such as creating a dump from an ec2 instance wherein you installed MariaDB on Amazon Linux.