# Amazon RDS super user privilege

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have created Amazon RDS instance, but can't create stored procedures in it because I am missing super user privilege. How do I get super user privileges?

Instance: MySQL 5.7.11

Comment: How is this question not answered satisfactorily? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601692/mysql-amazon-rds-error-you-do-not-have-super-priviledges

Answer (score 7):

You will not get super privilege in AWS RDS, but there is a way to disable binary logging (thereby removing the need to have SUPER privileges for creating triggers). This is done by setting the variable [log_bin_trust_create_function_creators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators) to 1.

1. [Create a new RDS Parameter Group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html). Alternatively, you may modify your current parameter group (if its not the default parameter group) and skip steps 3-5.
2. Change the value of `log_bin_trust_create_function_creators` to 1 for that parameter group
3. Also change any parameters that have non-default values in the parameter group that your RDS instance is currently using. This is necessary because an RDS instance can only be associated with one parameter group
4. Modify your RDS instance so that it uses your new parameter group
5. Wait for the parameter group change to show in the event log
6. **Reboot the RDS instance**. `log_bin_trust_create_function_creators` is labeled as dynamic vairable, and therefore shouldn't require a restart, but I have always needed to reboot the RDS instance for the change to take effect. *Perhaps there is another way but I haven't found it.*

Comment: *"but there is a way to disable binary logging"*  No, there isn't.  Disabling binary logging would disable point in time recovery.  That's not what `log_bin_trust_function_creators` does.  It puts MySQL Server into a "trust me, I know what I'm doing" mode, allowing the server to assume users creating stored programs know what they are doing, and will not create anything unintentionally non-deterministic.  Please link to 5.7 or 5.6 docs. Although they are very similar, version 5.1 is EOL.