# MySQL Super privileges for data import

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql, super

I know this may exist already because it is such a simple question, but I have searched for a few days with no luck.

I have a google cloud sql instance, and I can't seem to import any data(data and structure) because root( or any user I create), does not have Super privileges. When I try to grant the SUPER privilege, I get a 'Access Denied' for the user.

Is there a way, by best practice, to set Super privileges, so that I can import data. Or is there another way, by best practice, to import data that does not require Super privileges.

I am open to any criticism and suggestions.

Thanks,
Sean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL/Amazon RDS error: "you do not have SUPER priviledges..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601692/mysql-amazon-rds-error-you-do-not-have-super-priviledges)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same experience, I could not use `LOAD DATA FROM INFILE` commands.  You may be able to follow the guide located at https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing or by constructing a REST API call mentioned lower on that page.

One thing to note if loading data from Cloud Storage is that the Default user account for the CloudSQL instance (you can find it in the CloudSQL console) will need permission to access the Cloud Storage bucket that the data is being loaded from.  This account may be different than the account which has permission to make the REST API call.