# Mysql Dump to Maria DB on AWS

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rds

I am trying to perform a mysql dump to a Maria DB instance on Amazon RDS however I encountered the following error

```
ERROR 1419 (HY000) at line 893: You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

Here is the contents of line 893

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/  /*!50003 TRIGGER `cart_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `order` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
```

I saw a similar error on another post where it mentions to remove the DEFINER text. This is line 893 prior to removing the DEFINER text

```
/*!50003 CREATE*/ /*!50017 DEFINER=`user`@`%`*/ /*!50003 TRIGGER `cart_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `order` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
```

The sed command I used to remove the definer text is as follows

```
sed -i 's/\/\*!50017 DEFINER=[^ ]*`\*\///' /tmp/db_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601692/mysql-amazon-rds-error-you-do-not-have-super-priviledges) and updated the value of log_bin_trust_function_creators to be 1