# Create My sql trigger for After insert , update another table column using inserted record

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER latest_user_task_status_trigger AFTER INSERT ON
    user_task_transaction_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        user_task_table
    SET
        user_task_table.user_task_status=NEW.user_task_status
    WHERE
        user_task_table.id = NEW.user_task_id;
END
```

I have created above query but it gives me following error
[image]

How can i resolve that.

Comment: You forgot to use `DELIMITER` before this, to allow you to use `;` inside the trigger.

Comment: Since there's only one statement in the trigger, you don't need `BEGIN` and `END`.

Comment: @Barmar how to add that DELIMITER  in my query

Comment: You just type it before the query. `DELIMITER $`

Comment: Read the duplicate question I linked to.

Comment: it gives me  #1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable) @Barmar

Comment: That's a completely unrelated problem.

Comment: If you're using Amazon RDS, it's probably [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601692/mysql-amazon-rds-error-you-do-not-have-super-priviledges)